# Text - the block doesnt center align

Tags: html, css

The whole div remains on left, I tried withe below but no luck

```css
.captionhome {
  width: 600px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="captionhome" style="text-align: center;">WARNING: This product contains nicotine. Nicotine is an addictive chemical.</div>
```

[image]

Comment: if you set a width, use margin:auto to center the box, text-align works on phrasing content within

Comment: and if you wan to keep the 50px on top and bottom use `margin: 50px auto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `captionhome` has a set width. Either change that to `100%` or add

```
margin: 0 auto;
```